# how to change function value by another function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have function a has property with this.name and another function b have same property i want to override the a of this.name to b of this.name

```
function a(){
    this.name = 'john';
}
function b(){
    this.name = 'Smith';
}
```

i want b.name should be 'john' how?

Comment: Let the `b` function use parameter used to specify the `name`

Comment: And what have you tried to achieve it?

Comment: *"I have function a has property with this.name"* No, the `this.name` in `a` and the function `a`'s `name` property are not related. (On an up-to-date JavaScript engine, `a.name` is `"a"` and `b.name` is `"b"`.) Separately: You'll have to give us a **lot** more context. How are you calling them? Why would you need to retroactively change how a function works? (That's usually -- but not always -- a Big Red Danger Signal.)

Comment: What about `function b() { a(); }` ?

Comment: The question is not clear Pls add something you really want.check once again

Comment: its a interview question asked me

Comment: i just want to change the name property.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the concept of [nested function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Nested_functions_and_closures) in javascript.Since a nested function is a closure, this means that a nested function can "inherit" the arguments and variables of its containing function. In other words, the inner function contains the scope of the outer function.

```js
function a(){
    this.name = 'john';
function b(){
    this.name = 'Smith';
    return name;
}
return b();
}
name = a();//call to function a overides the name
console.log(name);
```

Comment: I don't think this is what OP is looking for

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should consider using classes and object. Also, 'name' property for functions is reserved for their actual name.

```
function a(){
    this.te = 'john';
}
function b(){
    a.te = 'Smith';
}

a();
b();
console.log(a.te);
```